# Creating a RaphaelJS pie chart without a plugin

Tags: raphael, pie-chart, graphael

I know a pie chart plugin exists for Raphael JS, but I need to add extra programming that doesn't exist in it. How do you create a pie chart in Raphael JS from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have a look at the code thats used on [this](http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html) page. That's how I created my piecharts

Comment: While this example does have some good info, I'm looking for a clear explanation on how to create it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point. The example on that page is pretty clear. There is a pie.js file that does everything you probably need. In this, there is a function - piechart - that takes an (x,y) position and a radius for the centre of the chart. Also it takes a list of labels and values for the segments.  The two other things of interest to you would be the "sector" function, which creates the path from start and end angles, and the "process" function, which goes through the list of labels/values and creates a sector for each.

Comment: Honestly, download the example, play around with it, add debug information, see how it runs. You'll find that its a good example and pretty clear.